# Determine type of connected Bluetooth device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

When i pair a bluetooth mouse/keyboard to android device i can see mouse/keyboard icon near the device name. 
How can i determine in code the type of those paired devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to get type of the Bluetooth device.

```
    BluetoothClass cls = device.getBluetoothClass();
        switch (cls.getMajorDeviceClass()) {
            case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PERIPHERAL:
                switch (cls.getDeviceClass() & 0x05C0) {
                    case 0x0540: // Keyboard - 1314
                        break;
                    case 0x05C0: // Keyboard + mouse combo.
                        break;
                    case 0x0580: // Mouse - 1408
                        break;
                    default: // Other.
                        break;
                }
        }
```